# How to change Ubuntu 18 loading screen background?

Tags: plymouth, desktop-background

I want to change this loading screen background (the purple one), without changing the whole animation, just the purple background, without software, How can I do it ?

[image: ubuntu Loading screen]

I have found the files under

```
/usr/share/plymouth/themes
```

and that I should save the file and run the following command.

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

But what are the needed lines to do add in the files ?

Comment: You'll want to goggle "Linux Plymouth" for a variety of animations that can be used. I like Earth Sunrise myself.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I don't want to use any software nor a made animation by someone, I just want to put certain image for the background instead of the purple background or at least change it's color (with the same default animation)

Comment: You are already using Plymouth, that's the splash screen you are seeing now. I'm only suggesting you google all the different images and animations people have created over the years.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix nah it looks like things changed, there is no directory with the path /lib/plymouth/themes

Comment: That's well documented. Between 14.04 and 16.04 they moved it to /usr/share or something like that.